# Brightness Control missing on Debian 8

Tags: debian, gnome, hardware, x-server, brightness

I've been using debian 8 from some time, with version 8.9 on dell inspiron 5000 series. Brightness control is missing from the beginning. I don't see brightness controller at all. 
I installed xbacklight, but of no use. I tried things like:  xbacklight -dec 40 . But didn't give any result.

```
  ls /sys/class/backlight
```

returns empty.

Also: /etc/default/grub reads like this:

```
 GRUB_DEFAULT=0
 GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
 GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="initrd=/install/gtk/initrd.gz"
```

My lspci output is as follows:

```
 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
 00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
 00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
 00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
 00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
 00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
 00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
 00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
 00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
 01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
 02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

And cat /proc/cmdline returns -

```
 BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=21a0f22c-ec1c-4d3e-809d-ddbbb8019326 ro initrd=/install/gtk/initrd.gz quiet
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.